# Easy way to remove UserDefaults (without coding)

Tags: ios, iphone, userdefaults

I've seen that there are several ways to remove the `UserDefaults` via code.

I've deleted a testing app from my phone but the UserDefault values are still there.

Is there an simple way of removing the `UserDefaults` instead of implementing a function to delete them?

Comment: If you are deleting the whole app from the phone and reinstall it, userdefault shouldn't contains data, you might want to check how data has been filled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove the app from your phone all the *UserDefaults* will be removed automatically. If you want to remove a particular one, you can use `UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "key")`, or you want to delete all UserDefaults, use this: `UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)`. This will clear all of the *UserDefaults* that have been set by your code leaving you with a fresh slate just as if the app had been deleted and reinstalled.